# How to convert MM/DD/YY to YYYY-MM-DD in R?

Tags: r, date, types, lubridate

In my table "tab" is a column called "date" with the format MM/DD/YY and it is of type "character". How do I convert this to the format YYYY-MM-DD and the type "date"? Is there a (lubridate) solution?

Comment: With lubridate, `mdy(tab$date)`

Comment: Hi marvin. If you type the title of your question into Google, you get quite a few relevant hits from Stack Overflow at the top of the page that should answer your question.